# How to toggle btwn Word's track change comment and the text on Mac

Tags: mac, microsoft-word, keyboard-shortcuts

Is there a keyboard shortcut for toggling between a Track Changes comment and the main text body? I've reviewed the commands under the View category in Word's Tool menu/keyboard shortcuts, but none of the review commands seem quite right.

Thanks for your help,
Jill

Answer (score 0):

There is no keyboard shortcut to jump between main document and right hand comments pane called mark up area.

There could be some tricks.

1. If you select Review - Tracking - Show Markup, and there you click on comments, if that was already ticked, the tick will disappear, and comments pane will not be visible and you are back to main document.
2. In the same Review - Tracking - Show Markup, now if you click on Balloons - Show only comments and revisions online, if that was already ticked, the tick will disappear, and comments pane will not be visible and you are back to main document.

You can use either of these two method to create a macro that toggles 1. Show Markup - comments - on and off or 2. Show Markup - Balloons - Show only comments and revisions online - on and off.

And then you assign a keyboard shortcut to your macro. Then pressing that shortcut your comments pane will open or close. If you had clicked on "New comment" that will open, you type your comment there, then press this keyboard short to close the pane and you are back to main text body.

Comment: Thanks, I really appreciate your help. Could you walk me through how to set up a macro for turning the comments on and off? I'm new to macros so I am having trouble figuring out what exactly I should record. I've tried  clicking the Show Comments to tick and untick but nothing seems to happen when I assign that macro a keyboard shortcut. Again, thanks very much for your help and time.